# add associative array to jQuery object as attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes

Greeting

Нow to add the associative array to an jquery object?

examples:

```
<div id = "element"></div>

$('#element').attr('_mynumber', 10);
console.log($('#element').attr('_mynumber'); // OK, _mynumber = 10

$('#element').attr('_myarray', [1,2,3,9,8,7]);
console.log($('#element').attr('_myarray'); // OK, _myarray = 1,2,3,9,8,7

$('#element').attr('_myassoc', {val1: 10, val2: [1,2,3,9,8,7]});
console.log($('#element').attr('_myassoc'); // FAIL, _mynumber = [object Object] (only as string), _mynumber.val1 = undefined
```

Comment: *"All!"* that tone is not very welcomed here. But I guess you can use `$e.data()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data` to store additional information on an element instead of `attr`.

```js
$('#element').data('_myassoc', {val1: 10, val2: [1,2,3,9,8,7]});
console.log($('#element').data('_myassoc'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: big thanks! 
I've just came up with this method.

But this method is very effective for frequent use?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by *frequent*. `data` is basically a `getter` and `setter` on an object. It would sure be faster if you build somthing on your own, but it is not slow, because it is pretty simple. @Zhihar

Comment: frequency: 5-10 times per second